# API send via VFS TransportSender in WSO2 ESB

Tags: api, rest, wso2, esb

I write a simple REST API that accept files attached to a POST call. I'm able to write the file to the filesystem using VFS:FILE as endpoint `<address uri="vfs:file://c:\\wso2\filesend\\"/>`, but the API has two parameter defined in the API `uri-template="/{symbol}/{value}`, so the passed file is stored in sub-dir `c:\wso2\filesend\{symbol}\{value}\` not in the `c:\wso2\filesend\` as I wont. I've tried to manipulate URL with rewrite mediator but it doesn't work with VFS.
Any suggestion how-to obtain desidered result? Thnks in advance

Comment: You can add the above your comment as answer. It will be more readable.

Comment: Ah..ok, thnks Abimaran for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. Instead using rewrite mediator I obtain the desired result changing REST_URL_POSTFIX property (e.g. `<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat('/',get-property('uri.var.value'))" scope="axis2">` ). VFS now write my file in `c:\wso2\filesend\{value}`